# pip install is stuck at cloning - is it possible to download the package separately, store it and install it from that?

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, pip, django

I am trying to install and configure a Django/MongoDB setup.

I'm using [these instructions](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html)

These commands worked fine:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
```

But whenever I run

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
```

It gets stuck!

```
shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/home/foodballbear/myvenv/bin$ sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
[sudo] password for shubhendu: 

The directory '/home/shubhendu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/shubhendu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/django (to nonrel-1.5) to /tmp/pip-9mkpehf8-build
```

If I download the source separately, can I install it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have the same but after one hour it passes and reinstalls django. I don't understand how it happens but passed. I think it is not right.
Better https://github.com/nesdis/djongo and look inside setup.py 
what the django version

```
    Collecting git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
  Cloning https://github.com/django-nonrel/django (to revision nonrel-1.5) to /private/var/folders/0y/r25j6k916ql6zgsjqk7b7txc0000gn/T/pip-req-build-s0vxu1g4
Checking out files: 100% (5524/5524), done.
Branch 'nonrel-1.5' set up to track remote branch 'nonrel-1.5' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'nonrel-1.5'
django-pagedown 1.0.6 has requirement Django>=1.8, but you'll have django 1.5.11 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 2.1.4
    Uninstalling Django-2.1.4:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-2.1.4
  Running setup.py install for Django ... done
Successfully installed Django-1.5.11
```